# Touchscreen falsly registering multiple taps on single tap

Tags: touchscreen, lg-optimus-one

Half of the times my phone's capacitive touchscreen works fine, but the other half it **registers multiple taps on a normal tap or on a long-press**.

This malfunction happens much more often when the phone is operated while laying flat on the table (i.e. not hand-held).

When a human body part, like the palm of a hand in a normal operation scenario, is resting firmly against the back of the device the problems usually goes away.

I'd think this somehow has to do with the so called *"parasitic capacitive coupling problem"*.

Is this something characteristic of capacitive touchscreens in general?

Can it possible be fixed by tweaking some timing parameters in the touchscreen driver settings?

Comment: I got a similar problem, but I cannot see a pattern for the working and not working status. In fact the problem started appearing very seldom and now the problem is there most of times and seldom I get a few 10 seconds of proper functioning.
I agree that the problem should be something related to parasitic capacity, bad grounding of some parts in the phone, RF coupling, or similar. I am using a k-touch W808 Wistler. By the way it is a piece of crap.
Using a touchscreen testing utility I can see that the long press gets interrupted every 200ms approximately when moving around my finger.

Answer (score 2):

A common fix for this kind of problem is usually buying a case for your phone.

I also have this problem in Galaxy Mini, but ever since I bought a thick silicon case, my problem is solved. But this did not get rid of the **misbehaving touchscreen while charging** problem, which is probably caused by the flux of electricity messing with the capacitive display.